# If A ⊂ C and A ⊆ B ⊆ C, then A ⊂ B or B ⊂ C.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm lost on how to begin with this statement. All I know is that it holds true but I have no idea on actually proving it. Any tips on how to start?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would happen if $A=B$ and $B=C$?

Comment: It would then imply that A = C, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, and that's not true, given that $A \subset C$, right? And the conclusion is...

Comment: Do you mean $\subsetneq$ in your statements?  Often, $\subseteq$ is used the same way as $\subset$.

Comment: @Michael Yes you are correct.

Comment: @amrsa That either A ≠ B or B ≠ C, therefore A ⊂ B or B ⊂ C?

Comment: Yes, that it. By the way, you know you can accept an answer that you have already by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This works a way to acknowledge the answer which you said to appreciate by giving reputation points to the answerer and some to you to. See more on [How do I accept an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer), [Why should we accept answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\subset= \subsetneq$, we have:

- If $A=B\subset C$, using the fact $A\subset C$ we have $(A=)B\subset C$
- If $A\subset B=C$, using $A\subset C$ we have $A\subset B(=C)$
- If $A\subset B\subset C$, we have directly the conclusion
- If both $A=B$ and $B=C$ we have $A=B=C\implies A=C$ which is an absurd, as we assumed $A\subset C$

Thus we have proved that under the hypothesis $A\subset C$, $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ we can have $A\subset B \lor B\subset C$ but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, clears up a little confusion I've had with this question. Greatly appreciate it!